# What glue can I use for glass and polycarbonate bonding?

Tags: adhesives, medium-selection, glass

I need to glue round glass (20 mm) inside a round hole in polycarbonate (tight fit). Only the glass edge (1 mm thick) and polycarbonate edge (1.5 mm) are surfaces that will hold the glue bond.

Following glue properties are required:

1. Strong elastic bond
2. Glue has to be clear (if possible)
3. Salt water waterproof
4. Easily removable from glass OR if carefully applied doesn't spill on glass

Answer (score 2):

I actually like a 50/50 mix of Gorilla super glue gel, 
and Loctite Super Glue Professional Liquid.

The gel is a little thick, and the other is runny. Mix the two, and you get a great syrupy consistency that would be perfect for what you are trying to accomplish.

Drip a bit of both on a scrap piece of cardboard, then brush it on your surface with a toothpick.

Make sure your glue doesn't soak through your cardboard, because you don't want it to stick to the table. You could use a plastic-lid from a throwaway container instead.